# Getting these strange xcode/iOS errors when building for android unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging, facebook-unity-sdk

**Things in use :**

1. Unity editor version: **2019.3.0f3**
2. Firebase Unity SDK version: **6.8.1**
3. Firebase plugins in use (Auth, Database, etc.): **Analytics and Messaging**
4. Additional SDKs you are using (Facebook, AdMob, etc.): **Facebook**
5. Platform you are using the Unity editor on (Mac, Windows, or Linux): **Windows**
6. Platform you are targeting (iOS, Android, and/or desktop): **Android**
7. Scripting Runtime (Mono, and/or IL2CPP): **IL2CPP.**

First of all my project is completely unaware of iOS, I did not download iOS module either but still I'm getting these errors which seems to be related to iOS.
And I already followed [Known Issues](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#known-issues)
and deleted .NET 3.x two DLLs and now my parse folder looks like this -

[image: See this image]

After this I also did that Assets > Play Services Resolver > Version Handler > Update thing
But no luck, so here are the logs I'm gettin,

First Log :

```
BadImageFormatException: Could not resolve field token 0x040000dc, due to: Could not load type of field 'Firebase.Editor.XcodeProjectModifier:projectInfoDoc' (2) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. assembly:UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none> assembly:F:\Unity Projects\Space Invaders\Assets\Firebase\Editor\Firebase.Editor.dll type:XcodeProjectModifier member:(null) signature:<none>
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces+AttributeCallbackWrapper.OnPostprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <83a73882c51c4602b3d34743827d03e7>:0)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces+<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<OnBuildPostProcess>b__1 (UnityEditor.Build.IPostprocessBuildWithReport bpp) (at <83a73882c51c4602b3d34743827d03e7>:0)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.InvokeCallbackInterfacesPair[T1,T2] (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] oneInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationOne, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] twoInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationTwo, System.Boolean exitOnFailure) (at <83a73882c51c4602b3d34743827d03e7>:0)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler()
```

Second Log :

```
Error building Player: BadImageFormatException: Could not resolve field token 0x040000dc, due to: Could not load type of field 'Firebase.Editor.XcodeProjectModifier:projectInfoDoc' (2) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. assembly:UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none> assembly:F:\Unity Projects\Space Invaders\Assets\Firebase\Editor\Firebase.Editor.dll type:XcodeProjectModifier member:(null) signature:<none>
```

I'm stuck at this point and I couldn't think more, I searched everywhere but couldn't find anything, Hoping for the best ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by adding this **iOS Build Support** Module to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it just by closing Unity and reopening it again!